# Unable to up-vote a meta post from the iOS app on iOS 9 (beta)

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, ios-app

I'm trying to up-vote Q&A for ["Why we're not customer support for [company X or product Y]"](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y?cb=1) using SE app (1.3.1) running iOS 9 beta 1—get an error about being unable to do so with my account, to logout and try again; did so, still can't, was told by the app to tell you on "meta". I was just able to perform the action using El Capitan, however. And voting works for all other questions so far.

Comment: Now that the public beta has been released, is this still an issue?

Comment: It's difficult to say. I can't attempt to reproduce because I can't vote again on that question. I am able to up-vote another question on Ask Different Meta; then again, I was able to do that before — only ever encountered the issue with that one specific question. I will try voting more with the app and let you know if the issue persists. I am using beta 3 which to my understanding is identical to public beta release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> We support current and previous versions of all browsers with some reasonable amount of market share, but **not beta or development versions**.

<sup>Source: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported); emphasis mine.</sup>

iOS 9 updated many networking APIs and the list of known issues on the developer release notes for the first beta is long, even without developers providing feedback and reporting bugs yet.

Whilst it may be a bug with the SE app, it is also likely to be a bug in iOS 9, which may be fixed for final release. There's no point adding a workaround to an app just because something doesn't work quite right in iOS 9 beta 1, which isn't even the public beta yet.

Perhaps when iOS 9 public beta is released, pointers can be made towards features that are broken as it is likely that there are no more serious bugs in iOS 9, but iOS 9 has only just had its first (private) beta release.

Comment: I assumed as much. Still, I did what the SE app asked me to do.

Comment: And it was working on iOS 9 yesterday and works for other questions, FYI to any interested parties.

Comment: @sss4r That's more interesting then. Apple updated a lot of network APIs in iOS 9 that could be speculated to have broken something completely, but if it worked yesterday then that's a more interesting edge case. Personally I don't have iOS 9 on a device yet so can't test stuff myself.

Comment: Good to know, thanks, yeah I thought it was unusual because I am unable to reproduce it on any other question. I hope the info helps the SE devs.

Comment: I hope it does help the devs. The moderators can't really help, but this can reach the developers.

Comment: @sss4r for what it's worth, I think the mobile team will appreciate this bug report (while they officially don't support beta). One of the main reasons for betas it to help developers get familiar with changes, new features, removed features, etc. :)

Comment: That's precisely how I look at it, too, so whenever I install a beta OS and run into a glitch, I try to give the app's devs an early heads up :-) Just today I reported a bug for another app, and the dev wasn't even aware that the beta came out this week and based on that feedback started assessing generally how iOS 9-ready their app is.

Comment: @grgarside Your answer makes a lot of sense, and I agree completely. I just have one minor follow-up question for clarification purposes. What distinction between public and developer preview betas are you making? Public betas are a relatively new program, just within in the last year or two. Are the public betas supposed to be more stable? Thanks.

Comment: @sss4r Yes, the developer previews are meant for developers to experiment with the new APIs and changes and Apple can change anything at any time. The public betas are designed to include near-final specifications for APIs so that even if an API has a bug or two the app doesn't need to be changed as the spec won't change.