# Build 1.3.1.214 crashes in iOS 9 betas 1 & 2 when tapping a site name

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In build 1.3.1.214, the app will crash in iOS 9 betas 1 & 2 once tapping on the menu icon > sites > Stack Overflow (or any other site you're subscribed to).

Comment: iOS 9 isn't supported yet. If this will still happen when it will be out of beta, this would be a valid bug report.

Comment: This assumes it's an iOS beta bug... Aren't betas out to test compatibility before a product is released?

Comment: Related answer to another iOS 9 bug question: [Unable to up-vote a meta post from the iOS app on iOS 9 (beta)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258591/unable-to-up-vote-a-meta-post-from-the-ios-app-on-ios-9-beta/258592#258592)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Bug reports are good.  Apple has a history of not fixing regressions before shipping to the public.  What we don't want is bad reviews. ;)

Comment: Plus with public beta now ~5% of our users are on iOS9. Almost as much as iOS7.

Comment: @BrianNickel cheers, and welcome back! (as a side note, I think you have a room to unfreeze ;))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed in 1.3.1.215.

The core libraries appear to be using a new singleton for empty dictionaries `@{}` and that class doesn't implement a key constructor so `[[self class] dictionaryWithDictionary:foo]` was crashing the app.  I just gave up the instancetype return and am now doing `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:foo]` but Apple should fix this.