# Stack Exchange app not working on iOS 9 public beta?

Tags: bug, ios-app, iphone

I installed the brand-new iOS 9 public beta today, and when I open the Stack Exchange app (1.3.1), it displays the blue gradient loading screen, flashes a shot of a blank feed for a half-second, and then blacks out and exiles me to the home screen.

(For what it's worth, I'm on an iPhone 6, so there's no old hardware to blame the problem on. The app was working perfectly on iOS 8.4.)

UPDATE: Now most of the app is working fine. The one thing that isn't working is the left sidebar. The buttons related to my profile work fine, but whenever I try to use the sidebar to go to a different Stack Exchange site, it blacks out.  The About and All Sites screens also load, but when I select a site from All Sites, that also crashes the app.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259549/build-1-3-1-214-crashes-in-ios-9-betas-1-2-when-tapping-a-site-name - the comments on this question suggest that you may be using an unsupported configuration

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry. I figured I should notify the devs while iOS 9 is still in beta so that the issues can be fixed before the new software goes public.